# How to fill rectangles in my PowerApps project?

Tags: containers, powerapps, fill, rectangles

I'm working on a project in PowerApps and I need help with one functionality. On one screen, I have a container containing 8 rectangles, below which there is a button. I want the rectangle to be colored after clicking the button. On the previous screen, I have an input where the user enters a number (number of produced products). On the screen with rectangles, I have this data "stored", and it counts the number of produced products after each button click. This part is already functional. My problem is that the rectangle is only colored up to the count of 8, and then it doesn't continue. For example: the user enters the number 10, and each produced item is clicked with the button, gradually coloring the rectangles, but only up to 8... I want it to start coloring again from the beginning for numbers higher than 8 (since there are only 8 graphical rectangles in the container).

this is my code in button:

```
Set(OrderNumber, Value(orderNumbertxt.Text)); 
If(indexRectangle < Value(OrderNumber), 
Set(indexRectangle, indexRectangle + 1)
);
Set(rest, Mod(indexRectangle + 1, 9));
Set(farbaVyplne, rest <= Value(OrderNumber));`

this is my code in fill property for rectangles:
If(indexRectangle = 1 && farbaVyplne, Color.Blue, Color.White)
If(indexRectangle = 2 && farbaVyplne, Color.Blue, Color.White)
```

Answer (score 0):

After you increase `indexRectangle` by 1, check if it is greater than 8, and if so, subtract 8.

That means, when `indexRectangle` is set to 9, the next step reduces it back to 1 and you're back at your desired number for the fill color selection.

```
If(indexRectangle < Value(OrderNumber), 
   Set(indexRectangle, indexRectangle + 1);
   If(indexRectangle > 8, indexRectangle - 8, indexRectangle)
);
```

If your logic only ever increases `indexRectangle` by 1, you can also just use

`If(indexRectangle > 8, 1,indexRectangle)`

If, however, the `indexRectangle` value can already be far higher than 8 when it arrives in your formula, you can use the Mod() function to determine the correct corresponding value from 1 to 8

```
    If(indexRectangle < Value(OrderNumber), 
       Set(indexRectangle, Mod(indexRectangle,8); 
// the previous row will return 0 for a number divisible by 8, 
// so we now set it back to 8
       If(indexRectangle = 0, set(indexRectangle,8,indexRectangle); 
       Set(indexRectangle, indexRectangle + 1);
       If(indexRectangle > 8,1,indexRectangle)
    );
```

**Edit**: If you use this code to set the fill for each rectangle, they all reference the same variable, so you may want to set the fill color to be for rectangle 1

```
If(indexRectangle >= 1 && farbaVyplne, Color.Blue, Color.White)
```

and for rectangle 2

```
If(indexRectangle >= 2 && farbaVyplne, Color.Blue, Color.White)
```

and so on. This way, the colours persist when the value of `indexRectangle` increases.

Comment: If that resolved your issue, please mark the answer as described in the [tour]. If it didn't, please leave a comment, so I can follow up.

Comment: It works, but individual rectangle coloring doesn't work properly. It only works for every 8 rectangles, then it stops. Even though it counts up to the value user inputs, the 8th rectangle is always the last one to be colored, and then it doesn't continue. For example, when the user inputs the value 12, only 8 rectangles are colored, the rest remain in the default color. In the Fill property for each rectangle from 1 to 8, I have: If(indexRectangle = 1, Color.Blue, Color.White).

Comment: In your question you explicitly state that you have 8 rectangles. `I have a container containing 8 rectangles`. I showed you how you can fill them according to the logic you posted. "I want it to start coloring again from the beginning for numbers higher than 8 (since there are only 8 graphical rectangles in the container)." So, how come now you have more than 8 rectangles? I edited my answer to add some code for the fill property.

Comment: I have 8 graphic objects (rectangles) in the container. Outside the container, I have an input that contains the value entered by the user. When the user enters the value 10, clicking the button will color one rectangle and continue coloring until the eighth rectangle. If there are more than 8, it should start again from the beginning, meaning the remaining two rectangles in the same container should be colored.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and put these specifications in the question. Please also add a few use cases with different starting numbers, because it is not quite clear to me what should happen with the first rectangle if the starting number is, say, 5, or 8, or 22.